# Switch Tabs with a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm relatively new to programming and I'm facing the challenge of having 2 tabs in my activity. In each tab there should be a RecyclerView which is identical with the other.

[image]

My guess would be to update the datasource when the user switches the tab. So one activity with one RecyclerView cares about two tabs.
But as I read more and more about it people usually use fragments for each tab.

Why? Which approach is better?

Comment: what do you mean by "update the datasource when the user switches the tab"?

Comment: use `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` when switch Tabs and update UI of both `Fragments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use fragments, you have two lists so you can properly implement dragging between pages, and returning to either tab will properly keep current scroll. You can also keep data for each tab in separate fragment, which breaks down huge source files into something more manageable.

Tip for using multiple `RecyclerView`s with same item types is creating single `RecyclerView.RecycleViewPool` and keeping reference in activity to reduce number of `ViewHolder`s you need to create.